# Batch file, run next program if already running

Tags: batch-file

Basically I have a simple batch script just now that starts a program multiple times let's call it 1.exe, 1.exe will launch 20 times and then be killed after % amount of seconds (specified by a command line argument).

What I need done is if 1.exe is already running, launch 2.exe instead, if 2.exe and 1.exe are already running launch 3.exe instead and so on.

All the code I really have just now is

```
Timeout /t 20 /nobreak >nul
echo.
taskkill /F /IM %programname%
echo.
pause >nul
```

and also the launching of the 1.exe

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Few questions: 1. are the executables really called `1.exe`, `2.exe`, etc... is there a simple way to iterate through their names? 2. Do you need `2.exe` to be run only once, or if `1.exe` is not running at any point in time?

Answer (score 1):

The Batch code below launch 2.exe if 1.exe is already running, launch 3.exe if 2.exe is already running and so on:

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,20) do (
   for /F "skip=3" %%e in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq %%i.exe"') do (
      if "%%e" equ "%%i.exe" set lastExe=%%i
   )
)
set /A lastExe+=1
%lastExe%.exe
```